# Why is "ls -1 $fl | wc -l" not returning value 0 in my for loop?

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to add a condition in a for loop to check the existence of a file as well as check for file size > 0 KB.

Period file contains monthly data:

```
20180101
20180201
20180301
20180401
20180501
```

There are individual files created for each month. Suppose a file is not created for one month, (`20180201`), then the loop below should terminate.
For example:

```
xxx_20180101.txt
xxx_20180301.txt
xxx_20180401.txt
xxx_20180501.txt
```

```
if [[ $STATUS -eq 0 ]]; then
     for per in  `cat ${PATH}/${PERIOD}.txt | cut -f 1 -d";"`
     do
        for fl in `ls -1 ${PATH}/${FILE} | grep ${per}`
        do

        if [[ `ls -1 $fl | wc -l` -eq 0 ]]; then
            echo "File not found"
            STATUS=1

            else
        if [[ -s "$fl" ]];  then
                       echo "$fl contain data.">>/dev/null
           else

           echo "$fl File size is 0KB"
           STATUS=1
                    fi
             fi
        done
    done
fi
```

but `ls -1 $fl | wc -l` is not returning 0 value when the if condition is executed.

Comment: Any reason not to use the shell function to check for existence of a file?

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: (OT: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat)

Comment: Also, you should **never** name a variable you assign filenames to `PATH`; doing so will break your shell's ability to run external programs, because it overrides the `PATH` used to find executables (even if you don't `export` it, since changes to a shell variable with a name that overlaps an environment variable overwrite the latter). This is why [POSIX establishes a convention](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html) of using lowercase names for application-defined variables.

Answer (score 3):

The following is a demonstration of what a best-practices rewrite might look like.

Note:

- We do not (indeed, *must* not) use a variable named `PATH` to store a directory under which we look for data files; doing this overwrites the `PATH` environment variable used to find programs to execute.
- `ls` is not used anywhere; it is a tool intended to generate output for human consumption, not machines.
- Reading through input is accomplished with a `while read` loop; see [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for more details. Note that the input source for the loop is established at the very end; see the redirection after the `done`.
- Finding file sizes is done with `stat -c` here; for more options, portable to platforms where `stat -c` is not supported, see [BashFAQ #87](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/087).
- Because your filename format is well-formed (with an underscore before the substring from your input file, and a `.txt` after that substring), we're refining the glob to look only for names matching that restriction. This prevents a search for `001` to find `xxx_0015.txt`, `xxx_5001.txt`, etc. as well.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^ -- NOT /bin/sh; this lets us use bash-only syntax

path=/provided/by/your/code # replacing buggy use of PATH in original code
period=likewise             # replacing use of PERIOD in original code
shopt -s nullglob           # generate a zero-length list for unmatched globs

while IFS=';' read -r per _; do

  # populate an array with a list of files with names containing $per
  files=( "$path/$period/"*"_${per}.txt" )

  # if there aren't any, log a message and proceed
  if (( ${#files[@]} == 0 )); then
    echo "No files with $per found in $path/$period" >&2
    continue
  fi

  # if they *do* exist, loop over them.
  for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    if [[ -s "$file" ]]; then
      echo "$file contains data" >&2
      if (( $(stat -c +%s -- "$file") >= 1024 )); then
        echo "$file contains 1kb of data or more" >&2
      else
        echo "$file is not empty, but is smaller than 1kb" >&2
      fi
    else
      echo "$file is empty" >&2
    fi
  done
done < "$path/$period.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are over engineering here.  Just iterate over content of file with periods and search each period in a list of files.  Like this:

```sh
for per in `cat periods.txt`
do
    if ls | grep -q "$per"; then
        echo "$per found";
    else
        echo "$per not found"
    fi
done
```

Comment: `ls | grep` is innately buggy; see [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). And so is `for anything in $(...)` or its backtick-based equivalent; see [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) is also relevant.

Comment: I’d prefer `while read … < file` over `for … in $(cat file)` and `[ -e ... ]` over `ls | grep …`. Both prevent a bunch of probably unwanted behaviour.

Comment: I relied on the fact that file with periods has simple structure as shown in original post.

Comment: And running `ls` in a subshell (which is what the parenthese do - you could simply take them out) on each iteration is not very efficient. If you really wanted to parse `ls` output, you should get the listing just once and take it from there. But of course, you don't need`ls`; you could just check if a file with this date exists, like already suggested in earlier comments.

Comment: You've taken *one* subshell out, but `ls | grep -q "$per"` is still forking off three subprocesses and running `execve()`s in two after connecting them with FIFOs; it's *much* less efficient than using shell-builtin logic to avoid the need for either external program.

Comment: Do you mean POSIX shell or some advanced shells such as `bash`?

Comment: `ls | grep` also has the issue of false positives if a _substring_ of a filename is found or if the pattern contains some regex.

Comment: @MikhailVladimirov, there are some differences between bash's implementation and others (ksh does a better job at minimizing the number of subshells it uses; POSIX neither requires nor prevents these optimizations), but that `ls | grep` incurs a substantial startup cost is true almost everywhere; the closest thing you have to an exception is multicall binaries like `busybox` where both `ls` and `grep` exist in-process and so don't need to be `exec`'d.

Comment: period file is not simple, it contain month, month name, year, week etc separated by semicolon

Answer (score 0):

Here's a refactoring of Mikhail's answer with the standard http://shellcheck.net/ warnings ironed out. I have not been able to understand the actual question well enough to guess whether this actually solves the OP's problem.

```
while IFS='' read -r per; do
    if [ -e "xxx_$per.txt" ]; then
        echo "xxx_$per.txt found" >&2
    else
        echo "xxx_$per.txt not found" >&2
    fi
done <periods.txt
```

Comment: I assume `xxx` should not be treated literally here.

Comment: Who knows? It's in the question but you could of course be right.